# How to just get the path of an assembly rather than loading it?

Tags: .net, reflection, mono.cecil

I am looking at how the [runtime locates assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) and am wondering whether there is a way to just get the path of an assembly found by `Assembly.Load` rather than actually loading it?

The reason I need this is because `AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly` from `Mono.Cecil` requires a path directly to the assembly and won't go to the extra effort of trying to locate it for itself. I'd like instead to combine the functionalities of standard `System.Reflection` and `Mono.Cecil`.

Comment: Have you tried `Assembly.Location`?

Comment: That would work, but then the assembly would be loaded into the application domain. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono.Cecil uses assembly resolvers to get an `AssemblyDefinition` from an assembly name.

```
AssemblyNameReference reference = AssemblyNameReference.Parse("Foo, Version=1.0.0.0");
DefaultAssemblyResolver resolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
AssemblyDefinition foo = resolve.Resolve(reference);
```

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

You might be able to use AssemblyName. Unfortunately I'm not at my development machine so I can't test this. But AssemblyName is used in the mscorlib implementation of Assembly.Load().

I went diving into the CoreCLR to see if I could gain any insight into where the resolver actually looks for the file but was unsuccessful. If this doesn't work, you might try diving into the CLR yourself for answers. I narrowed it down to a [FindAssembly](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=FindAssembly&type=) call

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("YourAssembly versionwhateveretc");
var path = new Uri(assemblyName.EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath;
```

**Old Answer**

Does [ReflectionOnlyLoading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_ReflectionOnlyLoad_System_String_) work for you?

This should allow you to inspect/interact with the assembly metadata without fully loading it into the current AppDomain.

Comment: I tried it yesterday and got this exception: `System.IO.FileLoadException: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.` I'd like to avoid actually loading assemblies if possible due to various complexities most of which I am not even sure what they are.

Comment: Is your concern performance related, or does loading the assembly cause issues with what you're trying to do?

Another option is loading it into a new app domain to get the path, then close the app domain.

Comment: Good question. What I am trying to do is rewrite an interface module to the .NET API for a language that I am doing so it uses `Mono.Cecil` instead of the standard reflection. Right now I have the problem that compiling the types in just 4 assemblies takes roughly 0.6s which is insane. I haven't bothered measuring just how long loading the assemblies via standard reflection would take, but now that I've decided on a rewrite of the interop module I am trying as much as possible to avoid touching standard reflection.

Comment: The concern is performance related since obviously just finding the path of the assembly given its name should be much less expensive than loading it in its entirety.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/13e7c4368da664a8b50228b1a5ef01a660fbb2dd/src/vm/assemblyname.cpp it appear it does resolve the assembly without loading it :)

Comment: No, it does not work. `AssemblyName("mscorlib").EscapedCodeBase` returns a null string and so it did for another thing I tried. Is `FindAssembly` a private static method? If so, how should I make use of it? `assemblyname.cpp` reads like noise to me, so I am not sure how realistic diving into CoreCLR's source is for me.

Comment: I'm trying to find the code currently used to resolve assemblies. Unfortunately if the two options I provided aren't going to work you may have to reimplement the resolver in managed code for your usage.